# Figwheel not connecting to HTTPS

Tags: clojurescript, figwheel

I'm using [Figwheel](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel) to compile and debug my ClojureScript app. It is awesome!

I have one issue, which is that when my app is running locally with HTTPS `(https://localhost:3000)`, Figwheel doesn't recognize it and doesn't connect to the browser.

Do I need to add anything to my project to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what the problem was. Figwheel connects to the app through HTTP and not HTTPS, so I had to allow loading of unsafe script in order for it to work.